# How to show FAQs with multiple categories using React FAQ Component

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I am trying to create FAQ page in my react project using below package:

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-faq-component
```

I am able to show FAQ with 1 category.

[image]

I want to show questions/answers with different categories:

[image]

Code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import FaqData from 'react-faq-component';

function Faq() {
const [rows, setRowsOption] = useState(null);
const data = {
title: 'FAQ (how it works)',
rows: [
  {
    title: 'How do I change my password?',
    content: `Answer here.`,
  },
  {
    title: 'How do I sign up?',
    content:'Answer here.',
  },
],
};
return (
  <div>
    <h2 className="section-title">My FAQ&apos;s</h2>
    <div className="faq-style-wrapper">
      <FaqData data={data} getRowOptions={setRowsOption} />
    </div>
  </div>
);
}
```

If any other demo/library can give me desired output, please suggest those as well.

Comment: So what's the problem? Use one component `<FaqData>` per category, that's the point of components.

Comment: As @Arkellys suggested or you can look for Accordion components rather than FAQ ready components.

Comment: While libraries often take away a lot of the redundant work for you, in some cases there is no real good use case to use a library. Your FAQ looks like a pretty typical FAQ where you have grouped items that can be collapsed. I don't think you really need a library for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Arkellys I have used one component  per category & its worked for me. Thanks again @Arkellys.

I am adding answer below for more details:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import FaqData from 'react-faq-component';

function Faq() {
  const [rows, setRowsOption] = useState(null);
  
  const data1 = {
   title: 'FAQ (how it works)',
   rows: [
   {
    title: 'How do I change my password?',
    content: `Answer here.`,
   },
   {
    title: 'How do I sign up?',
    content:'Answer here.',
   },
  ],
  };
  
  const data2 = {
   title: 'FAQ (how it works)',
   rows: [
   {
     title: 'How do I change my password?',
     content: `Answer here.`,
   },
   {
     title: 'How do I sign up?',
     content:'Answer here.',
   },
  ],
 };
   
 const data3 = {
  title: 'FAQ (how it works)',
  rows: [
  {
   title: 'How do I change my password?',
   content: `Answer here.`,
  },
  {
   title: 'How do I sign up?',
   content:'Answer here.',
  },
 ],
};

return (
  <div>
    <h2 className="section-title">My FAQ&apos;s</h2>
    <div className="faq-style-wrapper">
      <FaqData data={data1} getRowOptions={setRowsOption} />
      <FaqData data={data2} getRowOptions={setRowsOption} />
      <FaqData data={data3} getRowOptions={setRowsOption} />
    </div>
   </div>
  );
  }
```